# Select activity manually in live layout inspector (Android Studio 4.0)

Tags: android, android-studio-4.0

Before `Android Studio 4.0` we had to select activity before getting layout inspector. This helped us to know the `current` activity name. But in Android Studio 4.0 automatically sync layout inspector with current activity. I didn't find any manual way to select an activity from the current stack.

**How to select activity like below image in Android Studio 4.0 live layout inspector?**

Basically I need to know current activity name with activity hierarchy list

[image]

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question accurately but why do you need to select it manually, with a live layout inspector you can just stop where you need to inspect? I think we still have option to select the particular activity under the `select process` option.

Comment: @Yeahia2508 I'm facing the same problem, i can't find out the activity name from the new Layout inspector. Did you able to find solution for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

File > Settings > Experimental 
uncheck Enable Live Layout Inspector

Comment: That menu option doesn't even exist.

Try: Android Studio > Preferences > Experimental

Comment: Not everyone is on Mac @BarryFruitman

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Android Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler) for this

[image]